# Is there any way to install PyOpenCV or OpenCV on Python 2.5?

Tags: python, opencv, windows-xp, python-2.5

I really want to get either PyOpenCV or OpenCV on my computer, but all the downloads are for Python 2.6 or Python 2.7. Is there any way at all to install one of these packages on a Windows XP computer with Python 2.5?

Answer (score 1):

You should install from source, the [installation page](http://code.google.com/p/pyopencv/wiki/Installation) says this works for Python 2.5 upwards.

Comment: I think I already tried that, and it gave me errors because the source was meant for Python 2.6 not Python 2.5. I can't use the first executable build, and right now I just use my Python 2.5 program to call a external Python 2.7 program, which I can use to call the base OpenCV modules using it's build for Python 2.7.

Comment: I just repeated what it says on the installation page, I do not currently have a 2.5 installation running. With the dependencies on boost and OpenCV a lot could go wrong. Have you asked on a PyOpenCV specific [mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/ctypes-opencv) if that minimum Python version is still true?